# Northern Europe tree identification

Tags: species-identification, botany

I've seen it in Nordic countries (Sweden, Latvia). It's a tree that reaches maybe 5 or more meters high and its flowers have a beautiful scent.

[image]

Comment: Looks like maybe a kind of dogwood, anyone?

Comment: Not a dogwood, they have 4 large petals.  I would put in the genus *Prunus* from the general appearance of the flowers and leaves (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus).  Could be any of a large number of domesticates, maybe the list is shorter that far north.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the common [*Prunus padus*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_padus), which flowers with its strong scent now in many parts of Sweden (including my yard). At least if you are referring to the common species found in the wild (there are planted domesticated varieties as well). It is common across many parts of Europe though, and not only the Nordic countries, and can be found in Asia as well.